# Is there a built in python function that returns 0 if the number is negative?

Tags: python-3.x

I am essentially looking for a built-in python function that does the following:

```
if num < 0:
 return 0 
else:
 return num
```

Comment: `max(num, 0)`??

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick you need.

```py
def clip_neg(n):
    return max(n, 0)

print(clip_neg(-1))
print(clip_neg(0))
print(clip_neg(1))
```

Comment: `min0` is a bad name for a function

Comment: @ddejohn, any suggestion ?

Comment: `clamp` and `clip` are pretty conventional

Comment: I had completely forgotten of clip, thanks for the reminder. Editing now.